# Memory leak problem NSAutoreleaseNoPool()

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsautoreleasepool

I am trying to create an immutable string. I am not initializing it with init, alloc or new but still the memory is leaking and its saying "object 0x234b533 of Class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking " here is what I am trying to do

```
NSMutableString *srn = [NSMutableString stringwithCString:devSID];

// devSID is *char
```

this leaves a leak. I have tried this too

```
NSMutableString *srn = [NSMutableString stringwithCString:devSID length:sizeof(devSID)];
```

but this too doesn't work, however if I try initialize it with a simple string like this

```
NSMutableString *srn = @"this is my string";
```

it works, dont have any idea whats happening around. I am not using init or alloc but still there is a leak. I would be obliged if anyone could help me out to resolve this issue

Regards

Umair

Comment: Are you not getting a compiler warning with the last one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this

[[NSString stringWithCString:"Hello"] retain];

retain is a way to assess object ownership on objects that you didn't initially create, so this extends our rule of matching every alloc with a release or autorelease

**Note: You have to balance your release count if you retain this object. If you will not release retained object then you will face memory leak problem.**

Comment: just a single line ... and this guy solved my problem ... thanks buddy

Comment: You'll need to balance that `retain` with a later `release` or you'll leak memory.

Comment: @paul @Omayr Actually the problem is that he has created an autorelease object in allocated Autoreleasepool.. thats why i suggested him to retain that object.. now the thing he has to release that object as soon as he is done with functional part

Comment: This answer is wrong, because it doesn't address the fundamental problem and will lead to a memory leak.  As Noah states, an autorelease pool needs to be in place or any autoreleased objects will leak.

Comment: @Brad: I guess I am the one who has posted the question and my issue is resolved now, and Taraq's answer is a perfect solution to my problem. A wrong answer is more useful if it can solve a real time problem than a correct answer which can't . The other answer got 5 votes but it is of no use to me that is why for me its totally useless because the person didn't pay much heed to what the question is and just wrote down a pet answer. So, Brad please give back this answer the votes it deserves.

Comment: Just a comment that just because something works doesn't mean it is the correct answer. Figuring out why your application is breaking and finding the correct solution for your break is the correct solution. This is just like putting duct tape on an airplane.

Comment: @Omayr - There is only one cause for the error message in your question, and that is a missing NSAutoreleasePool.  Therefore, Noah's answer is the correct one for the question asked.  Yes, you need to retain (and later release) an autoreleased object created within the pool if you wish to use it outside of that pool, but that was not part of your question.  Tariq's answer is incomplete at best, and could be harmful for developers who are just learning Objective-C memory management.

Comment: I did try the autoreleasepool believe me or not and I guess you won't. But still it was leaking even though I dint use an init or new stuff. The problem was that that the NSString was released as soon as it was  initialized even before the AutoReleasePool "release" would actually be effective. You don't have any background of problem but Tariq did have that. Therefore it was a problem oriented solution. And technically his answer his right. I did the same thing mentioned it the other answer but the memory was still leaking. Now decide was your interference worth it or not.

Answer (score 8):

The leak is caused by your autoreleasing an object without having an autorelease pool in place to take care of it. That usually happens when you're doing things apart from the main thread, via creating your own threads or just using the `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` convenience method. If you want to use the autorelease functionality (implied by the use of the `NSMutableString` class method here), you need to create an autorelease pool at the beginning of the block of code where you'll be using it and drain it at the end. In other words, something along these lines:

```
- (void)myBackgroundThing:(id)whatever
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableString *srn = [NSMutableString stringwithCString:devSID];

    // etc...

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Even if one *doesn't* want to use the autorelease functionality, many Cocoa objects will do so behind-the-scenes anyways, so it's almost always a good idea to create a pool for background threads.

Comment: Actually, in a reference counted environment, you should *always* create an autorelease pool for every thread that will use Cocoa. If you write a standalone command line tool, you should create an autoerelease pool in `main()` too.

Comment: There are two things that I would like to address

1) I have already tried this but the application crashes as soon as it insert this block of autoreleasepool and release. 

2) Why do I need an autoreleasepool since I am not using init with NSMutableString

Comment: You're using a method of `NSMutableString` that returns an autoreleased object. Therefore you need an autorelease pool. As for your application crashing when you add this, well we'd need to see more code.

Comment: @Omayr - The reason this causes a crash is probably that you create an autoreleased object within the scope of the pool, then try to access it much later on after the pool has been drained.  While Tariq's solution of just adding a retain may make this not crash, you're creating a memory leak if you don't create an autorelease pool and also release the retained object after you're done with it.  Noah's is the correct solution for the fundamental problem here.

Comment: @Brad - I am sorry you couldn't understand my problem and I am not trying to do what you have stated. And using Tariq's solution I have double checked my application and there is not even a single memory leak. Once I have accepted Tariq's it means my problem is solved than what is the point to discuss it over and again.

Comment: Because other people will read this and implement the solution that you incorrectly marked as accepted. Thus the issue will continue to haunt developers down the road. We've seem this with PHP copy-and-paste coding. Issues that were solved years and years ago persist to be a problem because of this type of coding. Brad is correct to comment and provide insight for any future developers who read this. That is why he posted.

Comment: @Omayr - Just because you don't see a memory leak in the Leaks instrument doesn't mean one isn't there.  Leaks can be very subtle, which is why developers need to understand the underlying memory management rules at play and not just slap `retain` on something and call it a day.  Even if Tariq's solution happened to work for you in this one case, Noah's approach is correct for almost all of the times that your reported error message occurs.